# Slight GOAT-fronting in GenAm

Tags: american-english, dialects, phonetics

According to the Wikipedia page, GOAT in GenAm is realized as a slightly fronted [ö̞ʊ]. I have also heard some GenAm(-like) speakers produce that variant, though others produced a completely back variant. What I wonder is the significance of the slightly fronted variant, and if it means that GOAT-fronting is spreading to GenAm (together with GOOSE-fronting, which is more advanced in GenAm).

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide links for the pronunciations you are referring to (links to audio samples is even better).

Comment: The slightly fronted variant can be heard in https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/En-us-row.ogg (a monophthongal version can be heard in https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/En-us-window.ogg). I currently have no audio for the truly back variant, but it can be found in people in the Inland North and North Central regions, among others.